# Bug? String.split chopping off empty trailing value

Tags: apex, string, bug

I have found this strange behavior by trying to write a unit test against a CSV Generator. It seems that if I try to split a string by comma, and there is an empty  trailing cell, these values are ignored. Oddly, leading empty cells are fine. Is this behavior a bug? Should I be using a different expression than `,`? Is there a version where it works as I expect?

**Script**

```
Integer repro(String commaSeparated)
{
    return commaSeparated.split(',').size();
}
system.debug('Should be 2: ' + repro('2,'));
system.debug('Should be 3: ' + repro(',,3'));
```

**Log**

> USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|Should be 2: 1
>   USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|Should be 3: 3

Comment: Always love to see a drive by down vote with no explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm), here you need to pass the limit which is optional one.

> The optional limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the list.
>
> If limit is greater than zero:
>   - The pattern is applied a maximum of (limit – 1) times.
>   - The list’s length is no greater than limit.
>   - The list’s last entry contains all input beyond the last matched delimiter.
>
> If limit is non-positive, the pattern is applied as many times as possible, and the list can have any length.
>
> If limit is zero, the pattern is applied as many times as possible, the list can have any length, and trailing empty strings are discarded.

So, passing `-1` as limit in this  `split(regExp, limit)` method gives me desired results.

```
Integer repro(String commaSeparated)
{
   return commaSeparated.split(',',-1).size();
}
system.debug('Should be 2: ' + repro('2,'));
system.debug('Should be 3: ' + repro(',,3'));
```

Comment: N.B. this behavior is version dependent, if I recall correctly. Previously, it worked like it did in Java 7, but was then changed to work like it does in Java 8. I don't recall where the version change happened, probably 28.0 or 32.0, but definitely worth paying attention to release notes and testing on the selected API version.

Comment: I have checked that at current version 45.0, it is perfectly working

Comment: Yes, but not all classes in an org might be at the same version. It's simply a word of caution for those that depend on this answer without checking the API version.